# Keycloak "Unexpected error when handling authentication request to identity provider" when trying to invoke AIA

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, keycloak, keycloak-nodejs-connect

**An otherwise working as expected** Keycloak Server is giving me a headache since I started to try and implement Application Initiated Actions.

### Prior Search

Because looking for the topic results in a sparse selection of hands-on material, I got to go through [the design document for AIA](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-community/blob/main/design/application-initiated-actions.md#flows), especially the flows section.

### Environment

- Keycloak 15

  - PostgreSQL Database Backend
  - Keycloak as k8s deployment
  - Client in use has temporary full scope for development purposes
- Node.JS backend with keycloak-connect and express as the Server

### What I've tried

According to the design document ([Here is an entry to google groups where it's said that the feature "pretty much turned out as designed"](https://groups.google.com/g/keycloak-user/c/sh67H2EvHDg)) flows should be constructed as

```
../realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth
    ?response_type=code
    &client_id=myclient
    &redirect_uri=https://myclient.com
    &kc_action=update_profile
```

which resulted in this code in my templating engine:

```js
`${keycloak.config.realmUrl}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=${keycloak.config.clientId}&redirect_uri=${new URLSearchParams("http://localhost:3000/account").toString()}&kc_action=update_profile`
```

`(pug variable) keycloak.config` is filled using `keycloak.getConfig()` where `keycloak` is the keycloak-connect instance.

The templating engine correctly substitutes the variables into a link that leads to my keycloak instance, where I am presented with (the german equivalent of) this error message:

```
Unexpected error when handling authentication request to identity provider
```

(German:

```
Unerwarteter Fehler während der Bearbeitung der Anfrage an den Identity Provider.
```

)

There are no other identity providers configured.

### Question

**How to correctly make the call to my Keycloak to kick off an AIA, if the way described in the design document leads to this error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my own research, I now got it to work.
The error message seems misleading because I don't have another identity provider configured on that instance.

The kc_action parameter is expected to be in ALL CAPS. So

```js
`${keycloak.config.realmUrl}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=${keycloak.config.clientId}&redirect_uri=${new URLSearchParams("http://localhost:3000/account").toString()}&kc_action=update_profile`
```

should be

```js
`${keycloak.config.realmUrl}/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=${keycloak.config.clientId}&redirect_uri=${new URLSearchParams("http://localhost:3000/account").toString()}&kc_action=UPDATE_PROFILE`
```

This needs to be documented somewhere for people to find, because I didn't see it explicitly mentioned in the "docs".

[I also raised an enhancement request to the Keycloak documentation to document AIAs officially](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/issues/1320)